# Element size inside div

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have a div with a textbox inside and for some reason i can't make the textbox wider than 50% of the div width. I tried to set the width manually in pixels but it will never grow more than that. In the design interface it grown normally but when i run the project it doesn't. Tried in all browsers, always the same result.

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:left;display:table" runat="server" id="DIVAdd">
<asp:TextBox ID="TBDes" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `width` attribute on an `input` element is only used for images.

You have to apply the width as a style.

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:left;display:table" runat="server" id="DIVAdd">
<asp:TextBox ID="TBDes" runat="server" Height="25px" style="width: 100%"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;text-align:left;display:table" runat="server" id="DIVAdd">
  <input type="textBox" ID="TBDes" runat="server" Height="25px" style="width: 100%" />
</div>
```

---

On the [**W3 Input Attribute Chart**](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input#HTML_Attributes) you can see what attributes apply to which type of input.

Comment: Still doesn't work, and for other values <50% it works fine as it is

Comment: If applying the style doesn't work then your `div` might not be going all the way across? Apply a `background-color`to your `div` and see if it goes across. Going by the code you posted it should work. If there is more elements and/or CSS influencing the elements you need to post those as well.

Comment: I did, first thing i checked. It goes all the way to where it should

Comment: When running your code, inspect the elements and using the browser debugging window check what actual style is applied to the textbox. If the styles work in isolation something else is influencing it unique to your code I think :(

Comment: Yes, i removed all the styles from the upper divs and the problem remains, even when I resize them the textboxt won't get more than 280px wide. I don't get it.

Comment: In Chrome, the browser debugger, while inspecting the element, should show you where the style is coming from. when looking at the style tab in the debugger window with the focus on the textbox you should see a chart with margin, width, etc.. and below a list of styles applied, when going to the width click the arrow beside it and it should tell you where it comes from, assuming it is overwritten. Also, try classes over inline styles, in case it's a .NET thing where it might not pass the styles down correctly? - That's all I can think of.

Comment: It comes from element.style and its set to 180px no matter what values i put on it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically i was using a MS Template and in the css page Site.css was this

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"] {
max-width: 280px;
}
```